# Passing opened dir as argument

Tags: c, linux, posix, opendir

I have the recursive function in C :

```
void dir(char *file_name, char *dir_name) {
    DIR *f=opendir(dir_name);
    if(f==NULL)
        perror(dir_name);
    else {
        struct dirent *a;
        while((a=readdir(f))!=NULL) {
            if(strcmp(a->d_name,".")!=0 && strcmp(a->d_name,"..")!=0 && a->d_type==4) {
                char s1[250];
                strcpy(s1,dir_name);
                if(s1[strlen(s1)-1]!='/')
                        strcat(s1,"/");
                strcat(s1,a->d_name);
                if(strcmp(a->d_name,file_name)==0)
                {
                    printf("%s\n",s1);
                    n++;
                }
                dir(file_name,s1);
            }
            else
            {
                if(strcmp(a->d_name,file_name)==0)
                {
                    n++;
                }
            }
        }
    closedir(f);
    }
}
```

What it actually does : it looks for "file_name" inside "dir_name" and its subfolders and count how may times the "file_name" appears on that hierarchy.

I simply call it in `main()` like `dir(argv[1],argv[2]);` ( some C program with arguments "`./program_name file_to_find.txt directory`" ).

Actually everything works perfectly but i don't want to open the directory inside `void dir()`. I want it to open in `main()` and pass its data as an argument to `dir()` ( so the parameter `char *dir_name` ) should be modified.

Is there any way to do stuff like this ( to pass an opened directory as parameter to a function ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really simple

```
void dir(DIR *f, char *file_name, char *dir_name)
{
    struct dirent *a;
    int n = 0;

    while ((a = readdir(f)) != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(a->d_name,".") != 0 && strcmp(a->d_name,"..") != 0 && a->d_type == 4)
        {
            char s1[250];
            DIR *next;

            strcpy(s1, dir_name);
            if (s1[strlen(s1) - 1] != '/')
                strcat(s1, "/");
            strcat(s1, a->d_name);

            if (strcmp(a->d_name, file_name) == 0)
            {
                printf("%s\n",s1);
                n++;
            }

            next = opendir(s1);
            if (next != NULL)
            {
                dir(next, file_name, s1);
                closedir(next);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (strcmp(a->d_name, file_name) == 0)
            {
                n++;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    DIR *f;

    if (argc < 3)
        return -1;

    f = opendir(argv[2]);
    if (f != NULL)
    {
        dir(f, argv[1], argv[2]);
        closedir(f);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What about `dir_name` parameter? looks like you do not pass this in `main()`

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks. That `n` inside `dir()` looks like have some problems since it's throw from function, but nevermind for moment, i've used it globally ( it's a small program, just this void and main ).